# User can change is own rights with Item-specific security in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using Jenkins 1.593 and have trouble with the security configuration.

I would like as administrator to give configure rights to certain user to certain jobs (let's call them JobAdmin).

Then the JobAdmin will be able to give access to other users on the job they have access with the rights they need by using the security table inside the job (let's call these users JobUser).

I started using the project based authorization. My problem is the JobAdmin can modify is own rights in the security table loacted inside the job.
For instance he can give himself "Manage Ownership" right and then modify the owner of the job.
Besides by adding JobUser (with configure rights) the JobAdmin lets JobUser be able to modify their own right.

I am not sure I was clear but my aim is to provide project based security without letting user be able to change their right on the job even if they have configure access on this job.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find a plug-in that fits to your needs. Not sure if this is what you need, but you can try:https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin